# How to start a process with a predefined (in case it is unused) PID?

Tags: macos, process, launchd, pid

Is it possible to start/run a process with a predefined PID? In Linux or in OS X (or BSD)?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: to set a monitor for a specific PID before the process started

Comment: Then maybe you're doing the "monitoring" thing wrong...

Comment: I was going to say. Maybe you can explain what you really need to do? (And see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem please.)

Comment: @grawity: why wrong? its a bit more then monitoring (instrumentation). I just want to see what is going on in the process from start on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to start a process with a predefined PID.

If you wanted to do this you'd have to change the implementation of the `fork()` (and subsequent) system calls when a new process is spawned, and somehow create a utility that lets you intercept these calls. Also don't forget that the specific implementation of PID allocation depends on the operating system's kernel – it's not the same for OS X and Linux.

See also: [How does Linux determine the next PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid)

Comment: Odd, I could have sworn the Linux `clone()` syscall had a custom PID flag from the "checkpoint/resume" patches. But I guess those weren't merged.

Comment: is it possible (maybe with any workaround) to use a dtrace/gdb to start a process, pause it immediately after assigning a pid, get it's pid, start a monitor/filter for monitor for that pid and then resume the process?

Comment: @static: You don't even need a workaround for *that* – it's basic `fork()` and `exec()` usage. Instead of forking a process that immediately execs another program, fork a process that *stores its PID* and then execs another program.

Comment: @grawity: hm, is it possible to rewrite/customize a fork for an OS X and for a binary program, which process is interesting for me?

Comment: @grawity I think you meant *Checkpoint/Restart*? I wasn't aware this existed, so thanks for the info. Looked into it a little and it seems it wasn't ever merged, no.

Comment: @slhck except for `init` of course ;-)